# bundle does not respect gemrc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've configured gem source with gem command, now gem rc is like

```
---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- http://rubygems.org/
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

However when I run `bundle install` it still fetches from `https://rubygems.org`,

How can I change it to http scheme too?

P.S https is slow in my local network, so I need to use http connection instead.

Comment: According [this](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/commit/d80077386db82ad97fad8499ec0f2524132eeef0) bundle should respect gemrc configuration.

Comment: Is your source specified in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

### Change Your Gemfile Source

> How can I change it to http scheme too?

Installing gems retrieved over an unauthenticated HTTP connection is insecure. However, if you insist on doing it then you need to set the source line in your Gemfile. For example:

```
# Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

When you run `bundle install` in a directory containing a Gemfile with this source line, it will use the HTTP scheme to reach rubygems.org rather than the more secure HTTPS scheme.